# SSH server listening on multiple ports with passwordless access not allowing connections to second port

Tags: networking, ssh, security

I have my Synology NAS running an SSH server listening on the default port 22 and I set up passwordless authentication with a public/private key and a passphrase:

From sshd_config:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
Port 22
```

Everything works fine here, the problem is that I wanted to listen on another port besides 22 so I added the following line to sshd_config and restarted the server:

```
Port 5984
```

When I connect from my client using port 5984 and same private key (ppk) that I generated before I get a login prompt but as soon as I enter my passphrase the client shuts down. However, If I connect using port 22 everything works fine..

Any ideas why this happen? Do I need to generate another private key file after adding the second listening port or is it just a setting in sshd_config that I'm missing?

**Edit:**
I have a firewall running on my NAS and I added port 5984 to be allowed. Here the output from iptables -vL:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
35992 8607K DOS_PROTECT  all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere

    6   336 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5984
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:5984
   15   828 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
```

Here is the Putty log after trying to connect to my NAS ssh client using port 5984:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.03.14 11:16:34 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
login as: root
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20131004"
Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20131004": 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

**Edit2:**
sshd_config file:

```
Port 22
Port 5984
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox          # Default for new installations.
UseDNS no
ChrootDirectory none
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Verbose SSH connection output to port 5984:

```
DiskStation> ssh -vvv -i id_rsa2 -p 5984 root@localhost
OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 5984.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "id_rsa2" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file id_rsa2 type -1
debug1: identity file id_rsa2-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6p2-hpn14v4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [localhost]:5984
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[localhost]:5984" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-cbc'
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-64-etm@openssh.com
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-cbc'
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 19:e9:39:02:b9:32:c5:a5:f8:2d:c1:fc:fc:30:c0:b0
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:5984
debug3: put_host_port: [localhost]:5984
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[localhost]:5984" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "localhost" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: id_rsa2 ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa2
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa2':
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 21:25:09:ac:79:97:31:ac:37:d4:99:61:9f:1d:09:f8
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:5984).
debug1: Final hpn_buffer_size = 2097152
debug1: HPN Disabled: 0, HPN Buffer Size: 2097152
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Enabled Dynamic Window Scaling
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 4
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 4
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 87380
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 4
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 4
Permission denied, please try again.
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 4
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 4
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: tcpwinsz: 87380 for connection: 4
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Connection to localhost closed.
Transferred: sent 3268, received 1456 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 109919.7, received 48972.8
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Diff between working connection (port 22) and failing connection (port 5984):
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a firewall running on the NAS? (see e.g., `iptables -vL`)

Comment: I do have a firewall running on the NAS but I added a rule to allow connections to port 5984. (See my updated question)

Comment: just double-checking, did you restart sshd?

Comment: Yes @gogoud I restarted the whole NAS.

Comment: Post the complete content of your `sshd_config` file, and the output of `ssh -vv -p 5984 nameoftheserver true`.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles I have added the info you requested to my question.

Comment: For debugging purposes, I find the contents of `/var/log/secure` on the SSH server to be most useful source of information. After restarting the SSH server you should see `Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 5984`. It would then be useful to see what messages are logged after one of the failed connection attempts.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I usually create a *second* sshd process with its own configuration file. (`sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd-2222.conf` for instance) or by overriding the configuration on the command-line (`sshd -p 2222 -o PasswordAuthentication=no,AllowRoot=no`). This way they share the same keys, etc, but you can override any of the parameters.

> Any ideas why this happen?

I have some ideas:

1. selinux is enabled and is preventing you from using the port to login. This isn't likely, because if the problem were selinux, it wouldn't get that far. Run `selinuxenabled && echo "SELinux enabled" && getenforce` and if it is enabled *and* enforced, `grep sshd /var/log/audit/audit.log` to identify failures. Disable to see if it goes away.
2. PAM is getting in the way. Again, this doesn't seem likely, since PAM doesn't care about what port you use in conjunction with SSH.
3. `/etc/hosts.allow` or `/etc/hosts.deny`. Here you can associate port-service-user in any number of combinations. If these files are empty, we have to look elsewhere.
4. Did ssh add some mysterious port number to the key? It's possible. Your logs indicate it is and is not happening. See, for instance:

   debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
   Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:5984).
5. From the changelog in CentOS7:

   ```
   * Fri Oct 26 2012 Petr Lautrbach <plautrba@redhat.com> 6.1p1-2
     - add SELinux comment to /etc/ssh/sshd_config about SELinux command to modify port (#861400)
   ```

OK, so maybe *it is* selinux.

Comment: My answer was up-voted. Was it actually useful?